# What's causing my PHP code for adding a secondary description field to Woocommerce brands page to not work correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

This code below adds a second description perfecting the woo-commerce brand's terms page. After adding text to the second description, it shows well on the frontend (public) but it shows a blank space on the admin editor field. I'm not a pro developer but I managed to put up this code by consulting blog posts. Where am I going missing in the code below? Please I need all your help.
/**
*  Adds a secondary description field to brands
*/
class Custom_PWB_Secondary_Description{
static $field_name = 'Secondary description';
static $field_desc = 'Here is the secondary description';

```
    function __construct(){
        add_action( 'pwb-brand_add_form_fields', array( $this, 'secondary_desc_add' ), 9, 1 );
        add_action( 'pwb-brand_edit_form_fields', array( $this, 'secondary_desc_edit' ), 9, 2 );
        add_action( 'edited_pwb-brand', array( $this, 'save_desc_add' ), 10, 2 );
  add_action( 'create_pwb-brand', array( $this, 'save_desc_add' ), 10, 2 );
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', array( $this, 'add_desc_to_brands_page' ) );
    }

    /**
     *      Adds the extra field to 'edit-tags.php' page
     */
    public function secondary_desc_add( $taxonomy ){
        ?>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="tag-secondary-description"><?php echo self::$field_name;?></label>
             <?php
  $settings = array(
     'textarea_name' => 'Secondary description',
     'quicktags' => array( 'buttons' => 'em,strong,link' ),
     'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,blockquote,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,link,unlink,separator,undo,redo,separator',
        'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
     ),
     'editor_css' => '<style>#wp-excerpt-editor-container .wp-editor-area{height:175px; width:100%;}</style>',
  );

  wp_editor( '', 'seconddesc', $settings );
  ?>    
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     *      Adds the extra field to 'term.php' page
     */
    public function secondary_desc_edit( $brand, $taxonomy ){
        $sec_desc = get_term_meta( $brand->term_id, 'secondary-description', true );
        ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row"><label for="secondary-description"><?php echo self::$field_name;?></label></th>
            <td>
                            <?php
  $settings = array(
     'textarea_name' => 'secondary-description',
     'quicktags' => array( 'buttons' => 'em,strong,link' ),
     'tinymce' => array(
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,blockquote,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,link,unlink,separator,undo,redo,separator',
        'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
     ),
     'editor_css' => '<style>#wp-excerpt-editor-container .wp-editor-area{height:175px; width:100%;}</style>',
  );

  wp_editor( '', 'seconddesc', $settings );
  ?>
                <p class="secondary-description"><?php echo self::$field_desc;?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    
    }

    /**
     *      Saves the secondary description as term meta
     */
    public function save_desc_add( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '' ){
        if( isset( $_POST['secondary-description'] ) )
            update_term_meta( $term_id, 'secondary-description', $_POST['secondary-description'] );
    }

    /**
     *      Adds the secondary description content after the brand archive page loop
     */
    public function add_desc_to_brands_page(){
        if( is_tax( 'pwb-brand' ) ){
            $brand = get_queried_object();
            $sec_desc = get_term_meta( $brand->term_id, 'secondary-description', true );
            
            ?>
            <div class="secondary-description"><?php echo $sec_desc;?></div>
            <?php
            
        }
    }

}
new Custom_PWB_Secondary_Description();
```